# Why is `app/etc/di.xml` stored in `app/etc` and not in (lets say) `vendor`?

Tags: magento2, di

The default DI configuration of Magento 2 is placed in `app/etc/di.xml` alongside other configuration files like `env.php` and `config.php`. While the latter are files that you are meant to modify, the `di.xml` should not be modified at all. If this is so, why is this file not placed in a folder like `vendor` (for instance `vendor/magento2-base/etc/di.xml`)? For newbies, this might be confusing as they don't know which files they are allowed to modify and which not.

Comment: Not sure exactly but my guess because magento consider that as a global file which gets used for both vendor and app/code. Like global preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I can speculate and try to find some arguments for it.
It's not `vendor` because vendor is reserved for packages. And `di.xml` is not part of a package.
Making a package as you suggest `vendor/magento2-base/etc/di.xml` would introduce unwanted dependencies.
The global `di.xml` is there just to provide composition for your application so it should be part of your application.
I have a strong feeling that is also used by the installer, and not only the application.
So having it a module means that theoretically it can be disabled and you don't want that.

Look at it as a global configuration file for your application.

Comment: Thanks Marius. To further comment, actually `app/etc/di.xml` originates from `vendor/magento2-base/app/etc/di.xml` because the `magento2-base` is not much more than a package to kickstart the Magento filesystem. But because `magento2-base` is the base of every M2 project, it does make sense to reuse its `app/etc/di.xml`. However, its a copy and copying files is always ugly :) I like your comment on that a module could be disabled and therefore the global DI configuration should not be in a module. However, `magento2-base` and `framework` are not modules, only composer packages.

Comment: Hello @marius, How app/etc/di.xml file is initialized and when?Please let me know in detail.